# Elastic search Connection refuesd error

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have problem!

I want connect elastic search another computer. but it is not easy
use elastic search -2.2.0

almost searching result are this. so I try it.

config/elasticsearch.yml

[image: network snapshot]

but my terminal

[image: terminal screenshot]

Help me.....

Comment: share the output for this command: sudo lsof -i TCP | grep 9200.  Is there any firewall preventing connection on port 9200?

Comment: I solved this problem. I think restart is ctrl+c -> start but that is not. haha thank you reply!